# Django subtraction of two query sets

Tags: django, django-queryset, subtraction

I have two such query sets:

```
productin = ProductIn.objects.values('product_id').annotate(Sum('qty'))
productout = ProductOut.objects.values('product_id').annotate(Sum('qty'))
```

Each of query sets draws me: 'product_id' and 'qty__sum'

I would like to subtract 'production' from 'product out' to receive 'product_id' and the result of the subtraction 'qty_sum'